# Hypernym: Word that means 'window' or 'door'

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, hypernyms

There's the Italian word *serramento* which means "a window or a door", used in this way for example:

> Our company produces [*serramenti*] in aluminium.

Is there an equivalent word or expression that refers to doors and windows in general in English?

Comment: What is an aluminum window? Windowpane?

Comment: What is the difference between *serramenti* and *finestra*?

Comment: @MattЭллен finestra = window; serramenti = windows and doors

Comment: @sq33G there are windows made of aluminium, e.g. http://www.stegbar.com.au/products/windows_and_doors/aluminium/

Comment: So how do you know when serramenti are windows, and when they are doors?

Comment: @MattЭллен In Italian you don't use the word when you want to refer to a window or a door specifically. It's like *fruit* vs. *apple* and *orange*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is common to use the phrase 'doors and windows' as a class of objects that is part of a construction (typically part of what is known as joinery and woodwork). This suggests that there is no widely used and understood single word for this purpose.

In certain technical contexts, doors, windows, ventilators, etc., are collectively referred to as '*openings*'. (I could say *openings* increase the cost of a concrete structure.) You will notice that *openings* could be understood to be framed (in wood, metal, etc.,), rather than just an absence of material.

Comment: Perhaps combining the two suggestions offered thus far would work: *framed openings*.

Comment: Yes, to remove all possibility of doubt. However, 'framed openings' is often used only where expressly referring to framed ones and by implication excluding what may be unframed openings.

Comment: @onomatomaniak and Kris: Thank you! I was looking for a good name in English I could use as object/database table name. That seems to fit.

Comment: Btw, *serrare* means *to close / shut tightly* in Italian.

Comment: But a seemingly derived word *serration* means (something suitable for use in) cutting/ cut-out. An opening is a cut-out.

Answer (score 2):

"portal" seems to cover both doors and windows, although only widows that open as opposed to panes of glass that can also be referred to as windows but not portals.

Comment: This answer has been flagged by the system as a possible Low Quality Post. Where you are suggesting words or phrases you should also provide information about *why* you are proposing your suggestion. This typically includes links to external sources such as dictionaries and information quoted from those sources (and an accreditation of the source). Can you please add this to your answer to avoid it being deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that [ingresses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingress) or [egresses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egress) fit the bill, so long as the windows in question can be used to enter/exit. It is a slightly more narrow definition in that I guess it technically doesn't cover tiny windows or windows that don't open/close, but I've used it myself frequently and people typically understand what I mean.

Comment: This is not standard usage in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not entirely professional, but I have seen the term ***Windoors*** being used in software systems to cover windows, doors, skylight and glass panes. In your case I think the only real solution is to write *"windows and doors"*, because it would otherwise sound unprofessional.

I do agree however, that it would be nice to have a collective term that is more detailed than *"openings"* (not include e.g. ventilation openings), more collective than *"portals"* (include e.g. fixed windows) and more professional than *"windoors"*.

Answer (score -1):

Terms used to refer to multiple different types of openings (including doors, windows, and through-holes for piping/ventilation) as found in certain building codes throughout the english-speaking world are "[PORT](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/port)", "[PORTAL](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/portal)", "[FENESTRA](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fenestra)", or "[FENESTRATION](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fenestration)".
Click to see definitions on dictionary.com

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Braeden.  Including the definitions in your answer is encouraged.  When you do and compare them, what is the best fit for both windows and doors?  I do hope you take a moment to [edit] and see the [help].